# Temperature and humidity sensors on Samsung Galaxy S7 not available

Tags: android, galaxy, samsung-galaxy

Samsung S7 has temperature and humidity sensors. Many apps show those values. 
But if I use SensorManager I get null on both sensors.

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

Sensor tempSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
Sensor umidSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY);
```